# Eclipse gen folder have red x with no reason

Tags: android, eclipse, android-recyclerview, android-appcompat

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg2Az.png)

I have an eclipse project that import the android appcompat library from \android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat
My problem is the gen folder have red x and the layout-en file have red x and console doenst show any error, also in my project i have inflate          android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
 but it crashes on it when  open the activity: logcat show cannot inflate android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

Is this error related to the red x in gen ?

Comment: Ignore that, or, Click on build tab then select clean project

Comment: You'd better start using Android Studio